# Using CanCan and accessible_by outside of a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I am having trouble with defining a CanCan ability over a HABTM relationship such that it will work with the `accessible_by` method when I am NOT in the controller of the object

My model is as follows:

```
    Test <--HABTM--> Organisation <--belongs_to-- User
```

So I am trying to restrict `:read` access to Job objects as follows:

```
can :read, ImplicitTest, :organisations => { :id => user.organisation_id }
```

This works for the Test index page - only the correct tests appear. But when I try and pull down this list on a view within another controller by invoking `Test.accessible_by(current_ability, current_user)` it seems to produce some odd SQL:

`SELECT "tests".* FROM "tests" WHERE ('t'='f')`

Is there any way to make this call work outside of the TestsController ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should have been calling `Test.accessible_by(current_ability, :index)` - a lot of debugging got me the answer eventually.